# How to open Google Maps without other apps that use the "geo" scheme being opened?

Tags: android, android-intent, geo

I have a small test project with its main activity containing :

```
String myUri =  "geo:50.08818f,14.42021f?z=11";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUri));
startActivity(intent);
```

On my android device I have the Google Maps and an application that uses the geo scheme.
Running the test project, a popup with the 2 options appears: If I want to open my app, it opens and sets the given position on the map, but if I choose the Google Maps, the map opens and after one second, my other app starts and sets the position on its map.

My problem is that I don't understand why my other app opens if I haven't chosen it.
The piece of code in the manifest of my app is:

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused; you want to create an intent and make sure that Google Maps is the only app that responds?

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it can also launch Navigator...

---

You can also use :

```
"google.navigation:q=an+address+city"
```

for Google Navigation

---

Here is a list of available `Intent` :
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and longitude need to be decimal.

```
String myUri =  "geo:50.08818,14.42021?z=11";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this intent to open navigation using Google Map specifically:

```
 Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +
                     String.valueOf(AppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude())+","+
                     String.valueOf(AppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude())+"&daddr="+
                     String.valueOf(task.getLatitude()) +","+ String.valueOf(task.getLongtitude())));
                     navigation.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
 startActivity(navigation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with :

```
String uri = "geo:" + gpsLat + "," + gpsLong + "?q=" + Uri.encode(gpsLat+ "," + gpsLong);
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Hope this help